# No Amplify backend project files detected within this folder

Tags: android, react-native, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

How can I solve the issue of "No Amplify backend project files detected within this folder. Either initialize a new Amplify project or pull an existing project"
Am always having this issue on Windows with Amplify. I am following the TindeClone, just for me to come back to it after I took a break I got "Could not attach the backend to the project. Ensure that there are no applications locking the amplify folder and try again". These issues are frustrating me how how do I solve it and move on.
Here's the screenshot [image]

Thanks for you kind response.

Answer (score 9):

Simple delete the amplify folder in your project
run this
amplify pull --appId xxxxx --envName xxxx

and when asked for
Do you want changes backend select yes

This worked for me!

Comment: This one should be the accepted answer. It doesn't require deleting and recreating anything, and it includes the only step I missed. Namely, the question about backend changes is misleading. If you answer `No` it doesn't create a local backend and many commands such as `amplify export` don't work.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you have "amplify" folder one step inside the "TinderClone" folder?

Amplify cli could not locate an amplify folder inside TinderClone.

Try `amplify pull with these steps IN A NEW EMPTY FOLDER.

```
$ amplify pull
? Select the authentication method you want to use: AWS profile
? Please choose the profile you want to use: (Use arrow keys)
? Please choose the profile you want to use: default
? Which app are you working on? (Use arrow keys)
> amplifyapp (XXXXXXXXXXXXX)
  amplifyapp (XXXXXXXXXXXXX)
  newsBot (XXXXXXXXXXXXX)
  TodoApp (XXXXXXXXXXXXX)               
  ImageDownloader (XXXXXXXXXXXXX)
```

it'll fetches resources from the cloud.

Let me know what happened.

Comment: Hi @Waleed Ahmad, thank you for your kind response. I have tried "amplify pull" but it still gave me the same error message ''Could not attach the backend to the project. Ensure that there are no applications locking the `amplify` folder and try again". What could be the problem? And how can I avoid it happening again?

Comment: I tried running `amplify init` again, I discovered in my amplify folder /backend/backend-config.jason does not exist again. But I had it before, what could make it disappear?

Answer (score 0):

> Edit: take special note of Dylan's [comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69331650/no-amplify-backend-project-files-detected-within-this-folder/70426354?noredirect=1#comment132770750_70426354):
>
> This will erase the amplify project and resources in the cloud, then re-create. You can view instructions how to re-pull the existing environment within the amplify console under the "backend environments tab".
>
> `amplify pull --appId {amplify app id} --envName {env name}`

I was just recently struggling with the same blocker, after creating/deploying/testing an AWS Amplify project in my personal profile, I added a profile for my "client" (in this case, my brother), who created a specific AWS IAM user for me *in his account*.

The solution that I discovered, as per [this AWS blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/restoring-aws-amplify-project-after-deleting-it-from-the-cloud/), was to do the following from inside my project root folder:

1. (if not already done) remove the currently deployed Amplify stack, using `amplify delete`
2. delete the local "deployment information" file, using `rm amplify/team-provider.info.json`
3. re-initialise a new AWS Amplify stack (i.e.: in the cloud) and generate the relevant local files for it, using `amplify init`

   - *be sure to select the correct AWS profile or Key here for the new deployment, adding a new one if required..*
4. push your project to the newly initialised AWS Amplify stack, using `amplify push` for backend-only, or using `amplify publish` if you use Amplify Hosting

> Disclaimer: as I'm still learning AWS, so I may possibly use incorrect terms and/or examples to explain what I've learnt. This answer is most definitely open to clarification by the community.. Either way, I hope it helps.

Comment: This will erase the amplify project and resources in the cloud, then re-create. You can view instructions how to re-pull the existing environment within the amplify console under the "backend environments tab" `amplify pull --appId {amplify app id} --envName {env name}`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the .config file exists inside the amplify folder.
It contains all the required configuration files.

[image]